# String to Array in pipeline builder expression

Tags: azure, azure-synapse-pipeline

My Synapse notebook returns an array, `[1, 2]` I would like to Iterate through each element using foreach activity, How do I convert it to a `array from string`, so foreach activity runs for each element.

to keep it simple, I have created pipeline as below (hard coded the values for now)

Here are the pipeline parameters

[image]

For each activity properties, I used `@array`, but it is not parsing each element.

[image]

Here is the `Set Variable1` activity, inside foreach activity.

[image]

When I debug it is taking still taking it as string.

[image]

Can someone please help me, how to iterate through each element?

Comment: If you are forced to store the results of the Notebook as a string variable - then you might need to convert the string to an array first? (before you can use it in a ForEach activity)  One way to do it, would be to create a new VARIABLE of Type ARRAY - and have a SET VARIABLE Activity use something like:  @split(replace(replace(variables('arr'),'[',''),']',''),',')   - that will get rid of the square brackets, and split the string into an array.   You can now use that new Array Variable in your ForEach